# How to apply to each side of DodecahedronGeometry a unique texture?

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three js but i have managed to make polyhedron with one texture. but with multiple and with caption is somewhat advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying multiple diffuse textures in `three.js` requires the usage of multiple materials. `THREE.DodecahedronGeometry` as well as all other geometry classes derived from `THREE.PolyhedronGeometry` do no support multiple materials.

If you still want to use such a geometry with multiple materials, you need to define so called [group](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups) data. But since you are a beginner in `three.js`, it might be easier to create your mesh in a DCC tool like Blender, export it to `glTF` and then import it into your application via `THREE.GLTFLoader`.

`three.js R107`

Comment: Doesn't this seem more fitting to use UVs? `PolyhedronGeometry` generates them, so it would simply be a matter of identifying them and arranging a texture atlas correctly, or re-aligning the UVs to match an existing texture atlas.

Comment: The OP says he wants to use multiple textures. IMO, a texture atlas would be a different approach. In any event, I think working with Blender is the easiest solution.

Comment: I see, I missed the intent of the question. I thought OP was asking IF multiple textures were needed. Glad I only left a comment. :)

Comment: @Mugen87 what abt tooltips can you suggest any technique?

Comment: How about using [THREE.Sprites](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Sprite)? Another approach is the usage of HTML element with [THREE.CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer), see https://threejs.org/examples/css2d_label

Comment: Why is it so dodecahedron shows 36 faces instead of 12, so my textures are not put properly

Comment: A dodecahedron has conceptually 12 faces. However, `three.js` (and WebGL in genereral) is only able to render triangles, points and lines. So each face is represented as three triangles. 12 x 3 = 36 triangles

Comment: Is there any options to combine or merge those faces so that to have 12 faces only in star shape ?

Comment: No. Instead, the idea is to create group data for each of the 12 faces. You can then apply a material on each side of the dodecahedron.